# access class=column using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

How to access class=column with javascript and not using jquery

```
<div id="columns">
   <div class="column"><header>A</header></div>
   <div class="column"><header>B</header></div>
   <div class="column"><header>C</header></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. The easiest is to use querySelectorAll('.column') but it is new, so it will only work in modern browsers. Surely somebody else will post an answer that explains how to do it in a more compatible way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe. You will want to put this in a `window.onLoad` or `onclick` or some other function to make it work, but you get idea?

```
divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
for( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) 
{
    if( divs[i].className == "column" ||
        divs[i].className == "another-class" )  {
    //Do something here
    }
}
```

​
To search through elements that might have multiple classes try:

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/leereichardt/nrakE/)

```
divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
for( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) 
{
    var classes=divs[i].className.split(" ");
    if( searchStringInArray( classes, "column") ||
        searchStringInArray( classes, "test2") )  {
            divs[i].innerHTML="Changing";
    }
}

function searchStringInArray (stringArray, search) {
    for (var j=0; j<stringArray.length; j++) {
        if (stringArray[j].match ("(^|\s)"+search+"(?=\s|$)")) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
​
```

Comment: What if the div had more classes than `column`?

Comment: So you want to select multiple class names? Just do an `or` statement. I'll edit the answer...

Comment: Are you sure this can work for `class="column wide"` and `class="some-class another-class"`?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't quite understand what you mean. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

In almost all browsers except for older Internet Explorers, you can use

```
document.getElementById('columns').getElementsByClassName('column');
```

As IE<9 browsers do not have `getElementsByClassName`, you can iterate over the child nodes and testing if they

```
function getColumnDivs() {
    var results = new Array();
    var nodes = document.getElementById('columns').children;

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
       if (typeof nodes[i].tagName != "undefined" &&
           nodes[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == "div" &&
           nodes[i].className.className == "column") {

           results.push(nodes[i]);
       }

    return results;
}
```

The three conditions that are tested are

- does it have a tagName? (-> is it even an element?)
- is it a `<div>` ?
- does it have a `column` class?

Although the last condition precisely works only if it **only** has that class, but this probably still works for you.

Comment: You can also test for `nodes[i].nodeType == 1 &&  (nodes[i].className + " ").indexOf("column ") >= 0`. `nodeType 1` is element.

Comment: @rcdmk Yes, I couldn't remember the nodetype numbers off the top of my head, so I chose another alternative. What you suggest is, of course, semantically better. But! `indexOf("column") >= 0` is not correct. That would also select `<div class="this_is_definitely_not_a_column">` ;-)

Comment: You're right. I've added a space to the end but forgot the beggining: `(" " + nodes[i].className + " ").indexOf(" column ") >= 0`